# Modifying the conditional build expression in RoboHelp using Extendscript

Tags: extendscript

I'm trying to automate a process for our documentation team. They have a pretty big batch of framemaker files across several books and use RoboHelp to generate EclipseHelp for two different versions of our project.

Each framemaker file has the appropriate tags set to indicate which version a particular piece of documentation applies to. Currently the writers modify the conditional build expression to specify the correct set of tags and run File->Generate->EclipseHelp each time. I can run the generation process just fine, but I can't figure out how to change which tags it's using.

I've read through RoboHelp's scripting guide and the only references I can find to Conditional Build Tags is the ability to create and delete them. I can't find any references to Conditional Build Expressions. Does anyone know any way to modify it from a script? Alternatively, if someone can suggest a different way of organizing RoboHelp/Framemaker that is more conducive, I'm all ears, though I have basically zero familiarity with either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer with what I found - even though it's only a partial answer - just in case it can help someone, or possibly give someone enough to figure out a more proper answer.

Basically I found that each Single Source Layout has a corresponding *.ssl file. If your layout is called OnlineHelp, it will be (in my experience) OnlineHelp.ssl and will be in the same directory as your .xpj file. The ssl file is just a bunch of xml and has some number of sections. One of the sections will have the same name as the content category where you would go in the UI to change the Conditional Build Expression. In that section is an element named "BuildExpression". Set that to whatever you need and reopen your RoboHelp project. It's a bit of a hack, but I set up a groovy script to do that before running my ExtendScript and it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

The Conditional Build Expression forms form of your EclipseHelp Single Source layout. As such your script needs to refer to the tags there.

Comment: I found via undocumented calls that I can read the CBT (really should be called CBE) field of the appropriate ContentManager, but setting it does nothing. I suspect the fields would be marked read-only if the documentation could be found.